# How do i build a dictionary out of a tuple that holds lists of integers?

Tags: python

My code so far reads from two different csv files and prints them:

```
import itertools

def Compare(file1, file2):
    with open(file1+'.txt', 'r') as f1:
        with open(file2+'.txt', 'r') as f2:
            for line in itertools.product(f1, f2):
                lines = [[int(col) for col  in row.split()] for row in line]
                print(lines),
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1, 2130, 164, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1], [1, 186, 164, 61, 110, 50, 74, 1]]
```

I want to take those int values from the two lists and place them in seperate dictionaries where one key has 5 different values so for an example:

```
dict1={'key':'value1''value2''value3''value4''value5', 'key2:...etc}
dict2={'key':'value1''value2''value3''value4''value5', 'key2:...etc}
```

Where `dict1` is the `[0]` of the tuple and `dict2` is `[1]`.
And the values1-5 are values from each list of the tuple so `dict1` would hold `values[0][0:4]` for an example.

I want the outcome to look like this:

```
dict={164:[1,279,90,92,193]}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you require your final answer to be like, using a small list like you posted above.

Comment: When you say `tuple`, do you mean `list`?

Comment: note: you can put both with statements into 1 line

Comment: @Sukrit Kalra I guess my outcome example is not clear enough. I'll try explaining it better.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic I believe the output is a tuple that has two lists as the elements and each lists holds a number of integers. Am i wrong?

Comment: @wim i didn't know that, i'll try and see if i manage to do so.

Comment: @MaxPower : if you mean `[[1, 2130, 164, 279, 90, 92, 193, 1], [1, 186, 164, 61, 110, 50, 74, 1]]`, that is a list which contains two lists (each containing a number of integers). No tuples appear to be present here.

Comment: What is the criteria for the addition of a number into the list? Why do you leave out 2130 and not some other number? How do you chose your key?

Comment: The key is the 3rd column. For every identical key i want to print out all of the other 5 values.

Comment: But after leaving the key aside, you have 7 values. How do you choose 5 out of those 7? Randomly?

Comment: No, i need the 0,3,4,5,6 values. I thought it doesn't matter what values since i can just accustom whatever answer given to my specific values. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @kampu : "line" is a tuple here...

Comment: @MaxPower : The best thing you can do here is to give us an example of the first two lines in your two files, and the full result you are expecting from the 2 x 2 lines. With your edit above, you are have not accounted for what ''file2'' is used for.

Comment: @MrGumble sorry i forgot to accept your answer. It was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

def Compare(file1, file2):
    with open(file1+'.txt', 'r') as f1, open(file2+'.txt', 'r') as f2:
        for line in itertools.product(f1, f2): # line equals tuple of (f1[0],f2[0]), (f1[0], f2[1]), etc.
          # lines = [[int(col) for col  in row.split()] for row in line]
          # the tuple only contains 2 elements; first element should go to dict1, second to dict2. Why worry about that with list comprehensions?
          dict1 = {'key': [int(col) for col in line[0].split() ]}
          dict2 = {'key': [int(col) for col in line[1].split() ]}
          print(dict1, dict2)
```

Except: What is the key you are using? You refer to 5 values in each line in each file; but you have 8.

Comment: Why does it print every line in the number of total lines that i have? in this example its 65 lines in total so every specific line is repeated 65 times.

Comment: My key is supposed to be the[2] element from each list but i cannot access it as dict1[2]

Comment: How could i make the key line[0][2] for dict1 and line[1][2] for dict2?

Comment: My answers reflect your original code block without knowing what you are trying to achieve. 
With your recent edit, I can now see you want a dictionary whose key is set to the third element of a line in file 1. But what do you need file 2 for?